# MAUI use Google Drive API fails with Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth..."

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, maui, google-api-dotnet-client, .net-7.0

I have a MAUI app in .net7.0 and I'm trying to connect my app with Google Drive.
I completed the following steps:

1. Create a `project` in `google console`
2. Configure an `OAuth consent screen`
3. Configure an `OAuth 2 Client ID` of type `Android`

Inside the MAUI project I'm trying to create a `DriveService` like this:

```cs
public static async Task<DriveService> CreateAsync()
{
    try
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        string[] scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };

        using Stream stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filename: "client_secret.json");
        ClientSecrets secrets = (await GoogleClientSecrets.FromStreamAsync(stream)).Secrets;

        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            secrets,
            scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new NullDataStore());

        return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Greeks WT",
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error in this line:

```cs
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            secrets,
            scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new NullDataStore());
```

The error says: System.NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth..." for authorization; platform not supported.

Can someone point me in the right direction of how can I connect my MAUI app to google drive?
The only thing that I want is to be able to upload a file to the user google drive account.

Comment: We don't support MAUI for the Google Cloud client libraries at the moment. If you can get auth working, then *probably* the rest of the code will be fine - but auth is the tricky part. [`LocalServerCodeReceiver`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/main/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs) - which is what's throwing the exception - needs to both host a web server *and* launch a browser, both of which may be tricky across various mobile platforms.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have a MAUI hybrid application, so I guess I should try with a Web client. If you have any other suggestions on how I can make it work please let me know.

Comment: If you have a web service yourself, I'd recommend doing as much as you can server side, authenticating with a normal browser integration. It's hard to say more than that without more context, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm working on a MAUI Hybrid application and there is no server, only the mobile App.  Looks like this is going to be one challenging feature to add.

Comment: @WalterTorricos out of the box it works with API Keys, service accounts, and UWP.

Comment: @Jinjinov sadly I didn't make any progress. But I'll retake my work this weekend. I'll share my findings with you.

Answer (score 0):

Is designed for installed or desktop applications.  Which means its only going to work for an app run in UWP.

```
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            secrets,
            scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new NullDataStore());
```

Im currently looking for a way of detecting the application type so that I can spawn the correct authorization method.

Comment: @DalmTo Can we see the code for authorization in Android?

Comment: With .net I don't think such code exists at least not that I have ever seen working.  Hence my statement it will only work with UWP.    I did spend two days last week trying to no avail sadly it was very frustrating.   I even tried my old xamarin code it didn't work either.

Comment: Microsoft recommends using a backend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#why-use-a-server-back-end After searching for many hours, this is the only article on the internet that mentions how to do a login without a back end: https://blog.jhonatanoliveira.dev/google-login-integration-with-net-maui but it doesn't tell how to use it with Google Drive.

Comment: That's social login or authencation,   what we need is authorization. its a completely different flow.   I think what we need is pkce implemented in .net but I haven't had time to look more into it today.

Comment: Here it says "grant_type","authorization_code" https://github.com/jhonatanfernando/maui-google-authentication/blob/main/Article_001/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs#L38 is it not possible to use the AccessToken https://github.com/jhonatanfernando/maui-google-authentication/blob/main/Article_001/Models/LoginResponse.cs#L9 to make a REST API call?

Comment: With android the issue is the redirect uri.   You need to use mobile credentials from google developer console.    It seems maui from what i can see whats you to use web credentials but googles not going to let you register an app:// redirect uri for web auth.   For android and ios it will need to be something like this. [mobile](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#redirect-uri_custom-scheme)

Comment: If you can get [maui-google-authentication](https://github.com/jhonatanfernando/maui-google-authentication/blob/e4e367856ab8a62e20fb0ed72a0fb3f3b9ee2a65/Article_001/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs#L19) to accept a drive scope let me know you may be on to something.

Comment: What about https://github.com/Clancey/SimpleAuth/tree/main/samples/Sample.Maui ?

Comment: Again your not after login (authencation)  Your looking for Oauth2 authorization.  There is a difference.

Comment: Here is says you can make REST API calls: https://github.com/Clancey/SimpleAuth "The Simplest way to Authenticate and make Rest API calls in .Net" - I will try to change the scope from "www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" to "www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"

Comment: good luck.  let me know what type of client you create   you may need profile and drive scopes not sure its been a while since I last got google oauth2 working on Xamarin